# Expression for void filling welcome change

Tags: expressions

Is there an adjective/expression that conveys the meaning that this something fills a role/place that should have been filled long ago because of its high added value?

For example: *"The ____ exhibition on female figures in the development of modern design..."*

Perhaps "long-awaited" is something similar but I was hoping to find one that doesn't imply that people were expecting this change to happen.

Thanks!

Comment: Could “much-needed” fit in your context?

Comment: As a foreign speaker, I would say it would, but I don't seem to find many occurrences of "much-needed exhibition" for example. So while it does seem to convey the meaning, I was hoping to find something that is perhaps more widely used to convey the meaning. Thanks!

Comment: "much needed" or "ultimately expected" implies that people are eager to see such thing to occur. "Uncharted" conveys the idea of something  completely new and not previously described or experienced, but it applies to the subject of the exhibition, i.e.  *female figures in the development of modern design...*.

Comment: ***long-overdue*** doesn't *necessarily* imply that the recipients were anxiously awaiting delivery. It might be something they really needed, but were unaware of.

Comment: Much needed exhibition vs long overdue exhibition: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=long+overdue+exhibition%2Cmuch+needed+exhibition&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 5):

The expression **long overdue** (sometimes hyphenated as **long-overdue**) would work.

[Cambridge defines "overdue" as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/overdue)

> not done or happening when expected or when needed; late

You would be using the "when needed" sense, not the "when expected" one.